# Bring draggable div to the front in React.js when user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, z-index, draggable

I want to bring a draggable box to the front when I click on it or drag it.

I don't know in advance the maximum number of such boxes because I have a button that creates a new draggable box when the user clicks on the button.

The button should always be on top no matter how many boxes there are, so its z-index should always be the greatest.

So these are my problems:

1. How to bring a box to the front when the user clicks on it.
2. How to make the button stay at the front.

And I am new to ReactJS.

This is what I currently have in MyComponent.js

```js
import React, { useState }  from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function MyComponent() {
    const [currZIndex, setZIndex] = useState(0);

    const bringForward = () => {
        setZIndex(currZIndex + 1);
    }

    return (
        <Draggable onMouseDown={bringForward}>
            <div className="mydiv" style={{zIndex: currZIndex}}></div>
        </Draggable>
    );
}
```

The problem of my current implementation is that each component knows only its own z-index, but does not know what is the current highest z-index. And z-index increases whenever I click on any div, so this makes the z-indexes unnecessarily large.

If div1 has a z-index of 6 and div2 has a z-index of 2, I have to click div2 5 times to make its z-index become 7 in order to bring div2 to the front.

I still haven't come up with an idea on how to deal with the z-index of the button.

Fyr this is what I have in App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

function App() {
  const [componentList, setComponentList] = useState([]);

  function addNewComponent() {
    setComponentList(componentList.concat(<MyComponent key={componentList.length} />));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addNewComponent}>New Component</button>
      {componentList}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about the "stack level" of the item being dragged **and not the others** then set a z-index — any z-index — on that item only. Items without z-index (or with identical z-index) have their stack level determined by their source order ([specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)). So you would:

- Create a stacking context on the container (e.g. by adding `position: relative; z-index: 1`)
- Set `z-index: 1` on the element on drag-start and remove it on drag-end
- Set `z-index: 2` on the button

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rnlwp5?file=src%2FApp.js)

---

If you **do care** about the stack level of all items then there is absolutely no need to worry about "unnecessarily large" values — there is no restriction in CSS. You just need to keep track of the current highest z-index:

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q9nr2u?file=src%2FApp.js)

---

If you *really want to restrict the values for z-index*, then you need to:

- identify the item that is being dragged
- subtract 1 from all items that have a z-index higher than that item
- assign the largest value to that item

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdtz42?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 6):

Let's address the problems one by one. First the easy one:

#### 1. How to make the button stay at the top no matter how many boxes there are, so its `z-index` should always be the greatest?

One way to achieve this requirement is:

1. Wrap the `<button>` and `MyComponent` in a separate `div`.
2. Provide the `z-index` for `<button>` `div` higher than that of `MyComponent` `div`.
3. Use `position: relative` on both `button` container(`div`) and `MyComponent` container(`div`) to establish separate stacking contexts. You can refer ***[this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-reasons-your-z-index-isnt-working-and-how-to-fix-it-coder-coder-6bc05f103e6c/)*** article to read more about it.

Following the above steps the `button` will always be at the top no matter how many draggable elements you create.

```js
return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 2 }}>
        <button onClick={addNewComponent}>New Component</button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 1 }}>
        {componentList.map((item) => (
          <MyComponent
            key={item.id}
            zIndex={item.zIndex}
            bringToFront={() => bringToFront(item.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

#### 2. How to bring the draggable box to the top(but behind `button`) when user clicks/drags it?

Now, to solve this there can be multiple ways. One way which I would use is to play with the number of draggable component created in view. Let me elaborate by breaking it into steps.

1. Maintain a state in parent component which will keep track of total number of draggable components.

   ```
   const [componentList, setComponentList] = useState([]);
   ```
2. Make `<MyComponent />`(logically every draggable box) to accept two props; `zIndex` and `bringToFront`.
3. On click of `button` add a new entry inside `componentList`(i.e. setState) with the object:

   ```
    {
       id: prevComponentList.length, 
       zIndex: 0,
     }
   ```
4. Now, when a particular component is clicked or dragged(***[`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)*** event is triggered) and `bringToFront` callback function is invoked with `id` of that box. Now, map through the `componentList` and find the `id` of currently dragged/clicked element and *increase it's `z-index` value to max length of elements available in `prevComponentList` else(if the `id` does not matches the element `id`) decrease the current z-index by 1.*

   ```js
    function bringToFront(id) {
     setComponentList((prevComponentList) =>
       prevComponentList.map((item) =>
         item.id === id
           ? { ...item, zIndex: prevComponentList.length }
           : { ...item, zIndex: item.zIndex - 1 },
       ),
     );
   }
   ```

---

##### EDIT *(h/t [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a)*):

The above solution works for your current case. However, as you can notice the z-index is decremented unconditionally. To fix that we can put a condition on the zIndex that it should either be clamped to 0 or should lie between `1` to `total number of draggable boxes in view`(the second one looks more desirable). To achieve the aforementioned, you will need to edit the `bringToFront` function something like below:

```js
//... Rest of the code
{
        id: prevComponentList.length,
        zIndex: prevComponentList.length + 1, 
      },
// ...Rest
function bringToFront(id) {
    setComponentList((prevComponentList) => {
      const tempZidx = prevComponentList.find((item) => item.id === id).zIndex;

      return prevComponentList.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, zIndex: prevComponentList.length };
        } else if (item.zIndex > tempZidx) {
          return { ...item, zIndex: item.zIndex - 1 };
        }
        return item;
      });
    });
  }
```

***[DEMO IMPLEMENTATION](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serverless-voice-tj85jq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C7-13%2C9)***

**Suggestions and further reading:**

1. [4 reasons your z-index is not working](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-reasons-your-z-index-isnt-working-and-how-to-fix-it-coder-coder-6bc05f103e6c/)
2. [Using Styled components for styling](https://styled-components.com/)